# Calculate the percentage of zeros that I have in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column of catch rate data in a DF (df$catch.rate) that contains a combination of decimal values and zeros.

I would like to calculate the percentage of zero rows in the whole column to give me an indication of their contribution to the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sum(df$catch.rate %in% 0 ) / nrow(df)
```

I suggest using `%in%` if you have `NA` values..... e.g.

```
x <- c(0,NA,1) 
sum(x == 0 ) / length(x)
#[1] NA
```

Comment: However, this makes the assumption (large imo) that the missing values are not zero. @Sven;s answer below (with na.rm=TRUE added) does not make this assumption on the values of the missing.

Comment: `na.rm=TRUE` and my answer return the same answer regardless of NA presence. if there are no `NA`s then a faster but identical answer can be given with `==` . The assumption is the same in both our answers. if there are `NAs` you will not get the representation of zeros without removing them.

Comment: Im not sure i agree. Using the `x` from your example, `sum(x %in% 0 ) / length(x)` returns `0.33` , where as `mean(!x, na.rm=TRUE)` returns `0.5`, which seems more appropriate (imo). Apologies if i misunderstand.

Comment: because `mean(!x, na.rm=TRUE)` makes the *further* assumption that the OP doesn't want to know the proportion of `0`s in the entire column but instead only the data set that excludes NA values.

Comment: ok, fair enough, appears we disagree on how to deal with the missing data. For me, it is more appropriate to exclude the missing values from the calculation as we do not know if the value is zero or not. The %in% method assumes that it is not zero. But thank you very much for your replies.

Answer (score 9):

```
mean(!df$catch.rate)
```

will do the trick. You can add the argument `na.rm = TRUE` if there are `NA`s.

Answer (score 2):

```
nrow(df[df$catch.rate == 0,])/nrow(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sum(df$catch.rate==0)/length(df$catch.rate)
```

There's probably a more R-ish way, but this is the quickest I could come up with.